# How do I populate an address field programmatically if it is an autocomplete widget?

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a content type that is using the addressfield_autocomplete module so that I can use the map widget. The issue is, I need to be able to create nodes programmatically with the address field but also retain the autocomplete ability if nodes are manually created.

I get this:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCentroid() on a non-object

I'm including the country and all the addressfield default values.

It works fine if I turn off the autocomplete.

Any Ideas?